# auto refresh/reload any web browser without prompt after given period of inactivity plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking a Javascript plugin which will auto refresh/reload any web browser page without prompt after a certain period of inactivity.

Please someone know which plguin will be better. I just don't want to use any coding at this moment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use time interval and for refresh `window.location.reload()`

Comment: How is inactivity determined?

Comment: @guest271314, if there is no mouse or key movement. I already used window.location = window.location.href; window.opener.location.reload(); 
window.location.reload();
history.back();. But I am looking a plugin which will be better I think
        //window.location.href = window.location